# Loop for directories and files in R

Tags: r, loops, file, directory

I have a question about loop for my script. I have different directories and in each of them there are different files. My script analizes two files at the same time. I have for example file1, file2, file 3 and file 4. My script works analizing in couple file1-file2, then I have to do file1-file3, file1-file4, and file2-file3 and so on. So I have to analize each file with all the others without repetition. I was doing something like

```
dirs <- list.dirs()

for (d in dirs) {

files <- list.files()

a <- read.table("file1") ##what I have to write here? 
b <- read.table("file2")  ## and here?
dm <- dist(a, b , method = "euclidean")
write.table(dm, "file1-file2.csv")
}
```

My question is about calling file1 and file2 (and others too) after listed them. The format name file is like "1abc_A.txt"
thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following :

- Use `lapply` to loop over each directory.
- For each directory get all text filenames using `list.files`.
- Create every combination of 2 text files and apply the `dist` function to every 2 files.
- Write the output. If the directory is called `A` and filenames are `f1` and `f2`. It should write a file called `A_f1_f2.csv` in the working directory.

```
dirs <- list.dirs()

lapply(dirs, function(y) {
  files <- list.files(y, pattern = '\\.txt') 
  if(length(files) < 2) return(NULL)

  combn(files, 2, function(x) {
    a <- read.table(x[1]) 
    b <- read.table(x[2])
    dm <- dist(a, b , method = "euclidean")
    write.table(dm, sprintf('%s_%s.csv', basename(y), paste0(x, collapse = '_')))
  }, simplify = FALSE)
})
```

Comment: I got this : Error in combn(files, 2, function(x) { : n < m

Comment: 1) Check what does `dirs` return, if `dirs` is all the directories that you want to iterate over. 2) Also see the updated answer.

Comment: dirs returns 99 directories but directories are 98. Here they are  "."   "./6w41" "./6wps" "./6wpt" "./6xc2" "./6xc3". Also, with the updated answer I don't have the previous error but it doesn't find the file ".txt" , it seems that R is not opening the first directory

Comment: Use `dirs <- list.dirs()[-1]` to remove 1st directory and use the above answer.

Comment: okay for the directory, now I got error with file name. read.table(x[1]) : No input file found: check filename

Comment: It is difficult to debug because I don't have same file structure as you. I don't even have any data to run the code. What I can suggest is to break this down and apply it to one folder first and see if it works.